# when calling refreshToken() get the message com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-api, access-token, refresh-token

when calling refreshToken(), I get the message:

> com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401
> Unauthorized POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token

Here is my Credential creation code. I get accessToken and refreshToken using Spring Security. The application runs successfully until the expiration of the accessToken

```
  public void initCredential() {
    try {
      Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
      if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(properties)) {
        properties = createAdsProperties(managerProvider);
      }
      authorizedClient = authorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient(
          ID_CLIENT_PROVIDER,
          authentication.getName());
      credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
          .setClientSecrets(properties.getProperty(CLIENT_ID),
              properties.getProperty(CLIENT_SECRET))
          .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
          .setTransport(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport())
          .build()
          .setAccessToken(authorizedClient.getAccessToken().getTokenValue())
          .setRefreshToken(authorizedClient.getRefreshToken().getTokenValue());

//      TokenResponse response =
//          new GoogleRefreshTokenRequest(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
//              JSON_FACTORY,
//              authorizedClient.getRefreshToken().getTokenValue(),
//              properties.getProperty(CLIENT_ID),
//              properties.getProperty(CLIENT_SECRET)).execute(); //TokenResponseException 401

        credential.refreshToken(); //TokenResponseException 401

    } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e) {
      String errorMessage = e.getMessage();
      log.error(errorMessage);
      show(errorMessage);
      throw new CustomException(errorMessage, e);
    }
  }
```

the commented-out code also doesn't work

I have also aligned the areas in the code and in my account https://console.cloud .google.com/

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id=xxxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret=xxxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/google
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email,\
  openid,\
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.google.token-uri=https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.google.authorization-uri=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?prompt=consent&access_type=offline
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.google.user-info-uri=https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo
```

please help me!

**Updated**

example of DriveService initialization code

```
driveService = new Drive.Builder(
          GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
          GoogleConnectionService.JSON_FACTORY, googleConnectionService.getCredential())
          .setApplicationName(GoogleConnectionService.APPLICATION_NAME)
          .build();

 driveService.channels().stop(channel).execute();
```

if you delete the credential.refreshToken() line of code, the code will work successfully... within 1 hour, the user can call the Google api
after that, the message above will appear
Q: how do I update the access token?

Comment: What sample are you following because that just doesnt look right.

Comment: @DaImTo thank you for your interest in my question ! 
could you explain in more detail?
I read this https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2?hl=nb

Comment: yeah but where is authorizedClient getting your access token and refresh token from are they even set?

Comment: @DaImTo I use spring security, users log in to the app through a Google account
I can also successfully make requests to google API services until the access token expires

Comment: yeah but login authentication is not oauth authorization.   this library needs a refresh token feed to it for it to be able to refresh it I question if it's valid and how you are feeding it.    how about a custom datastore?

Comment: @DaImTo I updated the question... please take a look